# Is there a way to sort an array while applying a sorting threshold or hysteresis?

Tags: python, numpy, sorting

I am using numpy and want to use something similar to np.argsort to find the indexes of the k largest values along an axis in an array "array0".

However I would like to introduce a threshold (or hysteresis), so that the sorting becomes less noisy.

```
rand = np.random.random(size=(128,20))
slope = np.tile(((np.arange(20)+1)/20)[None,...],reps=(128,1))
array_0 = rand*slope
idx_sorted0 = np.argsort(array_0,axis=1) # <--- regular 'noisy' sorting
```

This is the regular, 'noisy', sorting. I would like to go along axis a(=128) and only introduce a change in sorted indexes of axis b(=20), if the value of the index b at a=i is greater than a threshold (e.g. 1.5x greater than the value of the index b at a=i-1).

With two for loops I could probably create a very slow method of iteratively going through the data and comparing every index to the indexes before. However with the size of the data, this is very unpractical and I am confident that there is a solution using vector operations or already existing Numpy methods.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my example output. I have an unsorted array a (indexes on the right):

```
[[0, 8, 3], 000
 [1, 4, 6], 111
 [8, 6, 4], 222
 [3, 1, 9], 333
 [4, 6, 2]] 444
```

sorting regularly will give this:

```
[[0, 1, 2], 034
 [1, 4, 3], 110
 [3, 6, 4], 322
 [4, 6, 6], 441
 [8, 8, 9]] 203
```

now I only want to change an index (from left to right), if the value on the right is 1.5x bigger than the value on the left:

```
[[0, 1, 2], 034
 [1, 4, 4], 112
 [3, 8, 3], 300
 [4, 6, 6], 441
 [8, 6, 9]] 223
```

This will produce an imperfect sorting but it will not shift indices as often. I hope I made my point clear. Sorry, a bit new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Could you post an example output of what you want?

Comment: Also, in the code above is `randvol` suppossed to be `rand`? If not how does the `rand` variable work itself into the picture, and where is `randvol` defined?

Comment: Sorry, yes, randvol=rand